CocoaPods manages third-party library import issues
In a swift project, when using CocoaPods to manage third-party libraries, why do some libraries only need to be introduced once, such as SnapKit（import SnapKit）, while others need to be introduced in every file, such as Kingfisher(import Kingfisher), HandyJSON(import HandyJSON)?
I tried looking for related answers but to no avail
